# IBM IDZ data tools platform missing

Tags: eclipse, zos

I have IBM ADFZ installed but for some unknown reason I don't have data tools platform installed. I don't have data source explorer view and data tools platform perspective on the client. I tried to install DTP like described here

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html

but during the process of installation it gives me registry error and then ADFZ stop loading at all. Then I have reinstalled ADFZ. How can I install data tools platform in a correct way?

I tried to install search for DTP in the client in the HELP -> Install new software

https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/htp/zos/tools/aqua3.3/

client gives me an error that repository isn't available now.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some of the downloads have been moved. This is where I found the new site to download.

https://ibm.github.io/mainframe-downloads/introduce-aqua33.html

Anyway, as you can see in this table,

https://ibm.github.io/mainframe-downloads/product-versions.html

Data Studio tools are available just up to 3.2.

Also, ADFZ doesn’t include the data tools:

https://www.ibm.com/products/app-delivery-foundation-for-zos

Maybe you just have to install the full Data Studio in the last version available.